# Как рассчитать какая из 3 точек на карте находится ближе всех к 4 точке, зная их координаты

Tags: теория

Есть три точки на карте расставленные в произвольном порядке (допустим по Москве) - a, b, c, d и я знаю их координаты (широта, долгота).

Как можно рассчитать, кто из a, b, c ближе всех находится к точке d?

Comment: Воспользоваться секретной формулой Пифагора. Или вот такой https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: [Расстояние между двумя точками на сфере](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5).

Comment: Вам поможет haversine formula https://www.google.ru/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/haversine-formula-to-find-distance-between-two-points-on-a-sphere/amp/

Comment: А как считаем? Между полюсами 12600 км или 20 000?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, ваш совет подходит лучше всего.

Comment: @FredPerry так считают в некоторых геоинформационных системах, в зависимости от языка программирования это уже реализовано во всяких библиотеках

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вычитаем вектора `d = (v1x - v0x, v1y - v0y)`, затем дистанцию с помощью теоремы пифагора, потом выбрать наименьшую дистанцию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это в декартовой системе координат, а вопрос про широту и долготу

Comment: В таком случае нужно посчитать угол между точками и умножить на радиус